# Asymptotic of an area integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics

I have the following integral
$$
I(\varepsilon) = \iint_D \frac{\sqrt{1+|\nabla h(u,v)|^2}}{[(h(u,v)+\varepsilon)^2+u^2+v^2]^2} du dv,
$$
where $h$ is a smooth function with
$h(0,0)=0 = h_u(0,0) = h_v(0,0)$, $D$ is a disk centered at the origin.

It seems like that the asymptotic of $I(\varepsilon)$ depends only on the first order behavior of $h$ at the origin, so the dominant term of $I(\varepsilon)$ is the same as that with $h\equiv 0$ and $$I(\varepsilon) \sim \frac{\pi}{\varepsilon^2}, \quad \varepsilon \rightarrow 0.$$

Any suggestion on how to prove/disprove it?

Comment: Does "smooth" mean $C^1$?

Comment: I was thinking $C^\infty$, or even just $h(u,v) = \kappa_1 u^2 + \kappa_2 v^2$ as a start.

Comment: Then split the domain of integration into $u^2+v^2\le\varepsilon^{4/3}$ and the complement.

Comment: Do you mean that the dominant asymptotic of $I(\varepsilon)$ comes from restricting the integral to the $\varepsilon^{4/3}$ disc? Why is it so? And would it help proving the $\pi/\varepsilon^2$ asymptotic? Thanks.

Comment: $\varepsilon^{2/3}$- disk, that is. Iosif used $3/4$ instead of my $2/3$, but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$
This is indeed a matter of splitting the integral. In polar coordinates, for some real $R>0$, 
\begin{equation}
 I(\ep) = \int_0^{2\pi}(J_t(\ep)+K_t(\ep))\,dt, 
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 J_t(\ep):=\int_0^{r_*}\frac{\sqrt{1+|\nabla h|^2}}{\big((h+\ep)^2+r^2\big)^2}\,r\,dr,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 K_t(\ep):=\int_{r_*}^R\frac{\sqrt{1+|\nabla h|^2}}{\big((h+\ep)^2+r^2\big)^2}\,r\,dr,
\end{equation}
$h:=h(r\cos t,r\sin t)$, $\nabla h:=\nabla h(r\cos t,r\sin t)$,
$r_*=r_*(\ep)>0$ varies with $\ep\downarrow0$ so that 
$$\ep<<r_*<<\ep^{1/2}$$ 
(e.g., one may take $r_*=\ep^{3/4}$), 
$a\ll b$ means $|a|=O(b)$, and $a<<b$ means $|a|=o(b)$.

We have $h\ll r^2$ and $|\nabla h|\ll r$, so that (as $\ep\downarrow0$) uniformly in $r\in[0,r_*]$ we have $h\ll r_*^2<<\ep$, $h+\ep\sim\ep$, $(h+\ep)^2+r^2\sim\ep^2+r^2$, $|\nabla h|<<1$, and $\sqrt{1+|\nabla h|^2}\sim1$. So, 
\begin{equation}
 J_t(\ep)\sim\int_0^{r_*}\frac{r\,dr}{\big(\ep^2+r^2\big)^2}
 =\frac1{2\ep^2}\,\int_0^{r_*^2/\ep^2}\frac{ds}{(1+s)^2} 
 \sim\frac1{2\ep^2}\,\int_0^\infty\frac{ds}{(1+s)^2}
 =\frac1{2\ep^2}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, 
\begin{equation}
 K_t(\ep)\ll\int_{r_*}^\infty\frac{r\,dr}{(r^2)^2}\le\frac1{r_*^2}<<\frac1{\ep^2}. 
\end{equation}
Thus, indeed 
\begin{equation}
 I(\ep)\sim\frac\pi{\ep^2}. 
\end{equation}

Comment: It seems like your claim $J_t(\varepsilon) \sim \int_0^{r_\ast} \frac{r dr}{(\varepsilon^2 + r^2)^2}$ follows solely from the assumption that $r_\ast(\varepsilon) << \varepsilon^{1/2}$ (and that $h$ has a vanishing linearization at the origin.) I could not follow the argument, but now also think that it cannot be true: if all I have is an upper bound on $r_\ast$ , then I can make it zero and then $J_t$ is also zero. (Put differently, the $1/(2\varepsilon^2)$ asymptotic cannot follow just from an upper bound for $r_\ast$.) Am I missing anything?

Comment: p.s. The proof for $K_t$ growing strictly slower than $1/\varepsilon^2$ is very clear, and uses only the lower bound for $r_\ast$.

Comment: @TYp : I have added details on the first asymptotic equivalence, $\sim$, in (1). In that equivalence, you cannot set $r_*=0$, because then the equivalence would become the nonsensical "equivalence" $0\sim0$. More importantly, the lower bound on $r_*$ given by $\varepsilon<<r_*$ is needed for the second  asymptotic equivalence in (1).

Comment: Now I see the lower bound is used and the doubt is gone. Thanks. The technical issue I have is how that "interchange of integral and asymptotic" in the first equivalence can be justified. For simplicity, if $h(u,v)$ is the radially symmetric $1/2(u^2+v^2)$. Then $J_t(\varepsilon)$ is exactly $\int_0^{\varepsilon^{3/4}} \frac{\sqrt{1+r^2} r dr}{[(r^2+\varepsilon)^2+r^2]^2}$. And the claim is that for small $\varepsilon$ this is equivalent to $\int_0^{\varepsilon^{3/4}} \frac{r dr}{[\varepsilon^2+r^2]^2}$. I am trying to figure out the (elementary?) missing lemma.

Comment: @TYp : When people write (as I did) "for $r\le r_*$ as $\epsilon\to0$", they of course mean "uniformly in $r\in[0,r_*]$  as $\epsilon\to0$" (which is how I have now rewritten that). So, the first equivalence in (1) follows by the general fact that, if $f_\epsilon(r)\sim g_\epsilon(r)>0$ uniformly in $r\in[0,r_*]$ (as $\epsilon\to0$), then $\int_0^{r_*}f_\epsilon(r)\,dr\sim \int_0^{r_*}g_\epsilon(r)\,dr$. This fact should be an easy exercise for you.

Comment: I have no doubt the proof works, but the only way I can make sense out of "$f_\varepsilon(r) \sim g_\varepsilon(r)$ uniformly in $r\in [0,r_\ast]$" is to show $\max_{r \in [0,r_\ast]} | f_\varepsilon(r) - g_\varepsilon(r) | \leq C \varepsilon^{-2}$. This would definitely imply the conclusion, but the uniform bound is tedious to show. Maybe I am missing a easier trick.

Comment: @TYp : No, you don't need to also show that $\max_{r\in[0,r_*]}|f_\epsilon(r)-g_\epsilon(r)|\le C\epsilon^{-2}$. 
You have $f_\epsilon(r)\sim g_\epsilon(r)>0$ uniformly in $r\in[0,r_*]$ (as $\epsilon\to0$).

Comment: Previous comment continued: This means that $\forall\delta>0$ $\exists\epsilon_\delta>0$ $\forall\epsilon\in(0,\epsilon_\delta)$ $\forall r\in[0,r_*]$ $1-\delta\le f_\epsilon(r)/g_\epsilon(r)\le1+\delta$ or, equivalently, $(1-\delta)g_\epsilon(r)\le f_\epsilon(r)\le(1+\delta)g_\epsilon(r)$, whence  $(1-\delta)\int_{[0,r_*]}g_\epsilon(r)\,dr\le \int_{[0,r_*]}f_\epsilon(r)\,dr\le(1+\delta)\int_{[0,r_*]}g_\epsilon(r)\,dr$. Thus, $\int_{[0,r_*]}f_\epsilon(r)\,dr\sim\int_{[0,r_*]}g_\epsilon(r)\,dr$. This is it.

Comment: Indeed this is much better. Thanks for the clarification.